# Socket.io returns 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm building a chat application with NodeJS, EJS as template engine and Socket.io. When I initialize Socket.io instance in my layout view, it breaks up with the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lzz8iVx 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here's my code on the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var layouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
// other dependencies

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(layouts);

// Here goes the server
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.set('transports', ['websocket']);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A client connected!');
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

And here's my **layout.ejs**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Node Chat</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/main.css' />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='javascripts/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- body %>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Though I did everything according to Socket,io docs, it results in the error stated above. I've also tried several variants, like change to `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)`, but it didn't work as well. Also I added `cors` library to my application, but it doesn't work also. What could be the problem of this?

Comment: What version of `socket-io` are you using?

Comment: Try without `io.set('transports', ['websocket']);`

Comment: @kemotoe when I first encountered this problem, I used `1.7.4` version. Then I upgraded to `2.0.4`, but it didn't work as well.
@mk12ok I tried to remove this line, it didn't work either

Comment: I took your code and socket.io 2.0.3 and it works when I delete the line `io.set('transports', ['websocket']);` and it gives Bad Request error with that line

Comment: @mk12ok it worked! could you please post that as an answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: it also works when you have `io.set('transports', ['websocket']);` on the server and `var socket = io({transports: ['websocket']});` on the client